# Transformations: Triangle Reflection

Tags: transformation, reflection

[image]

a.  Describe an image of the triangle reflected across the line $y=x$ (pictured above) and note the coordinates of the vertices.

b.  Describe an image of the triangle resulting from part a reflected across the x-axis and note the coordinates of the vertices.

c.  Define the single transformation that is equivalent to the two transformations performed above.

d.  Explain why these transformations are isometries.

Is my solution accurate?
[image]

Comment: Looks good. You can also note the transformation in part c is a clockwise rotation of 90 degrees

Comment: I think for part d you need to show that the distance is preserved. So $(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2$ will become $(y_1-y_2)^2+(x_2-x_1)^2$, and these are equal